# Getting "We did not find this address :(" error each time visit on user profile

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting error while each time user profile sections.

[image]

Now i am getting this error.

[image]

I have followed all the installation instruction but still getting this issue. Also /pt/users/undefined/edit is getting undefined. I think it is wrong. Please help me fix this issue.

```
Started GET "/pt/users/undefined/edit" for 163.53.151.26 at 2016-10-20 03:19:25 -0400 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.8ms) SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations" Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML Parameters: {"id"=>"undefined", "locale"=>"pt"} User Load (2.3ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deactivated_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = 0 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 Rendered catarse_bootstrap/devise/shared/_header.html.slim (7.9ms) Rendered catarse_bootstrap/errors/not_found.html.slim within layouts/catarse_bootstrap (600.2ms) Rendered catarse_bootstrap/layouts/_analytics.html.slim (9.8ms) User Load (1.7ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: some how you are sending `undefined` in the `id` parameter,
`107.170.104.166:3000/pt/users/undefined/edit` send some id such as `107.170.104.166:3000/pt/users/1/edit`

Comment: check with some availabe user id, if it works, then you have some thing wrong in the link, or the route

Comment: I am just doing normal site operation. Sign up a user then created the project underneath the system and it is open source framework. I didn't change anything there. https://github.com/catarse/catarse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by running postgres api client. Because catarse is a monolithic architecture application now. So we need to run the client in the system so could other functionality could worked.

```
./postgrest postgres://rails:test12345@localhost/catarse_development -a anonymous --jwt-secret gZH75aKtMN3Yj0iPS4hcgUuTwjAzZr9C -s 1 -p 3004
```